# ¿Como cambiar la plataforma de detino de .NET?

Tags: .net

Tengo la 4.5.2 pero ya instale el sdk de .NET 6 y no me lo detecta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 6 es core.. tal vez tu projecto no sea compatible?

Comment: con razón no puedo cambiarla, no es Core

Comment: Puede influir tambien la versión de Visual Studio. No todas las versiones son compatibles con todas las versiones del framework

Comment: Estoy utilizando la versión 2022 Enterprise